# Uniqueness of a General IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, lipschitz-functions

> Consider the IVP $$u'=f(x),$$ where $x\in[a,b], u(a)=\alpha$ and $f$ is continuously differentiable.

I was wondering if a unique solution to the IVP above.

My thoughts:

I was thinking that since $f$ is continuously differentiable and we suppose that $f'$ is bounded, this implies $f$ is also Lipschitz. Hence , if $f$ is Lipschitz and we restrict $f'$to be bounded then the IVP must have a unique solution. Is this true?

**edit**

If we do not impose the condition$f'$ is bounded, how else can we determine whether a unique solution exists? Can we conclude this from the domain of $f$?

Comment: $x(a)= \alpha$ ? Or $u(a) = \alpha $ ?

Comment: yes sorry, thanks for the spot

Comment: @Bell $f$ continuously differentiable in $[a,b]$ does not imply that $f′$ is bounded. Consider $$f(x)=\cases{ x^2\sin(1/x^2),&$x\ne0$ \cr 0,&$x=0$}$$ is continuously differentiable on $[-1,1]$ but its derivative is unbounded on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Yep, I understand. If we are given only the information in the yellow box above, can we use the fact that $f$ is continuously differentiable to link this to Lipschitz and then uniqueness?

Answer (score 0):

$ \int_a^x f(t) dt= \int_a^x u'(t) dt =u(x)-u(a) =u(x)-\alpha$. Hence

$$  u(x)= \alpha +\int_a^x f(t) dt.$$

Comment: Thanks. But I was hoping to use Lipschitz our properties relating to the Mean Value Theorem to solve this, as indicated by original question. For instance, can we use the fact the set is compact to Lipschitz and then uniqueness?

Comment: @Bell. Not that the solution of Fred works also if $f$ and $f'$ are not bounded, as you require in the latest edit to your question. It require only the standard (absolute) integrability of $f$.

Comment: Yep, thanks. I do want to know if $f$ is Lipschitz or not.

Comment: Since $f'$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ we have that $L:= \max \{|f'(t)|: t \in [a,b]\}$ exists. By the mean value theorem we get $|f(x)-f(y)| \le L |x-y|$ for all $x,y \in [a,b]$.

Comment: Nice! And hence a unique solution to the IVP?